# Consulta de data no calendario python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, query, calendario

Estou estudando python a pouco mais de uma semana, mas gostaria de realizar uma ação mais ou manos da seguinte forma.

sera colocado o valor monetário e coloca o dia de fechamento do cartão e o dia de pagamento da fatura.

quando realizar uma compra ele consulta o calendário e verifica, esta dentro da data de fechamento do cartão este mês ou não...

chegou no dia de pagamento da fatura automaticamente subtrai o valor que foi realizado nas compras de cartão de credito no mês.

Se alguém poder ajudar a entender, não estou conseguindo !

Obrigado !

I'm studying python with just over a week but would like to perform a more or less hands action as follows.

be the place the monetary value and the closing day of the card and the day of payment of the invoice.

when making a query he consults the calendar and checks, this is within the closing date of the card this month or not ...

arrived on the bill payment day automatically subtracts the amount that was made on credit card purchases in the month.

If I can help, I can not!

Thank you!

Comment: Olá Rodrigo, aqui é o SO em Português. Não é necessário a parte em inglês da sua pergunta.

Comment: Ok, obrigado não sabia !

Answer (score 0):

## Respondendo apenas ao titulo.

Bem vindo ao stackoverflow Rodrigo, você pode usar a biblioteca datetime e importar o [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). Da uma olhada nesse código para Python 3.

```
# importação da biblioteca datetime
from datetime import datetime

# Checagem dos dados nesse momento de acordo com o seu computador
data = datetime.now()

# Vamos 'formatar' a saída. Dia, Mes, Ano, Hora, Minuto e Segundo'
data_print = data.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

# Vamos exibir as informações
print(data_print)
```

## Respondendo a pergunta no geral

```
# Vamos importar o datetime
from datetime import datetime

# Vamos definir que esse será o dia da fatura
data_da_fatura = '05/04/2019'

# Checagem dos dados nesse momento de acordo com o seu computador
data = datetime.now()

# Vamos 'formatar' a saída. Dia, Mes, Ano, Hora, Minuto e Segundo' e converter para string com o str()
data_dados = str(data.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))

# Vamos usar o if para checar se a data da fatura chegou
if data_da_fatura == data_dados:

    # Um indicador que está funcionando
    print('subtrair')
```

A partir daqui, acho que você pode usar a criatividade para usar esses conceitos no seu estudo

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar !